# Complex Data Access with Large Data Sets

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have a system which has complex user permissions which determine which contacts a user can see in the application and I am looking at the best way of structuring the tables to enable us to scale. The permissions are too complex to work out on the fly so need to be written to a table which will then be updated whenever admin functions are performed or a contact is added/edited/deleted.

The contacts table has 10 million records in it. My first thought was to create a contactUserLink table which would have contactUserLinkID,contactID,userID with the clustered index on contactUserLinkID and a non clustered index on the contactiD and userID for quick searching on.

My concerns with this are this:

1. If we had 200 users and they all had different access to large parts of the data the contactUserLink could  balloon to 100s of millions of rows.
2. There would be a lot of adding / editing / deleting going on in this table as contacts were edited and admin changes on the rules occur.
3. Admin changes could lead to huge amounts of deleting / inserting as user permissions are re-worked which if they took a long time could leave users with no access.
4. If a new user is added and he has access to all the records writing 10 million records into that table isn't likely to be fast?

We are using SQL 2008.

I hope I have managed to explain that so that it makes some sense.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of granular user permissioning is not ideal. As stated in #4, writing a 10 million records to give an admin access to all contact is most definitely not scale-able.  Have you tried looking into role based permissioning?  Is this an option in your scenario?

Comment: The problem with Role based permissioning is that for a sales team where the permissions are based on territory etc each one has different access and therefore a different Role so you would still end up with a large amount of data that would have the same issues as above I think.

Comment: Then you can call it territory based permissioning.  Group territory userid together and grant territory admins access to a territory.  This way when an admin is created, you just need on row added to grant it access to an entire territory.

Comment: I don't know your limitations of your system but this sort of grouping/role/territory base permissioning will be worth your time to look into further.  You can have grouping + contactid.  Just have to union them when determining which contacts you have access to. First part will determine the contacts based on your group permissioning then union that with each individual contact permissioning.  I don't know if I'm making it more confusing.  If you've looked into this in depth and decided against it... maybe calculated columns? Indexed views? may help speed up your queries.

Comment: Thanks. This is how I started out actually and it works pretty well to a point. The difficulty is making the unions etc as simple as possible so that you don't start getting performance issues when retrieving the data which is why I started looking at another approach. Having looked at both methods over the last month or so I think that my initial approach (and what you have suggested) is the best if I can make the query simple enough. This approach means you don't have to actually store tens of millions of records and have the headache of updating them when territory/groups change.